# npm run build fail to compile. When npm audit fix, I got this

Tags: node.js, npm, create-react-app

background: I did coding for ReactJS app and wanted to deploy on Netlify or Vercel. When I `npm run build`, I got error.

[npm run build error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAvh5.jpg)

When I typed `npm audit fix`, I got this.

[npm audit fix msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yt0p.jpg)

I got stuck for days and dont know why I cant deploy my client app.

Here is my package.json file:

```json
    {    
      "name": "client",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@apollo/client": "^3.5.10",
        "@emotion/react": "^11.8.2",
        "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
        "@mui/icons-material": "^5.5.1",
        "@mui/material": "^5.5.3",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.3",
        "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.4",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
        "apollo-link-context": "^1.0.20",
        "graphql": "^16.3.0",
        "graphql-tag": "^2.12.6",
        "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "react-moment": "^1.1.1",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.2.2",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
        "semantic-ui-css": "^2.4.1",
        "semantic-ui-react": "^2.1.2",
        "svgo": "^2.8.0",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
          "react-app",
          "react-app/jest"
        ]
      },
      "browserslist": {
        "production": [
          ">0.2%",
          "not dead",
          "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
          "last 1 chrome version",
          "last 1 firefox version",
          "last 1 safari version"
        ]
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.1"
      },
      "proxy": "https://fathomless-mountain-12345.herokuapp.com/"
    }
```